# Django: Making ForeignKey not create a back-reference

Tags: python, django

I know that I can use `ForeignKey`'s `related_name` argument to control what the back-reference's name will be. But is it possible to avoid creating a back-reference completely?

(e.g., I have in Car a field ForeignKey(Person), and I don't want Person to have an attribute that leads backs to Car.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For those coming from Google: use a `+` in the `related_name` field to prevent creating a back reference field.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to do this? You don't have to use it if you don't want to.

In any case, the back-reference is only a code shortcut - it's exactly equivalent to `Car.objects.filter(person_id=person.id)`.

Comment: I want to avoid possible clashes with existing attributes.

Comment: @cool-RR.  Easy to do.  Use the `related_name` attribute to give it some non-conflicting name.  `related_name = 'some_non_conflicting_name'`.

Comment: That's an easy workaround, I agree. But I am looking for a way to have no back-reference at all.

Comment: @cool-RR: not having the back reference is impossible.  In SQL, it exists.  There's no way to stop it from existing.

Comment: Now that is an answer. You can post this as an answer and I'll accept it.